# AChartEngine - Charts with data from parse.com won't display

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, achartengine

I would like to create applications forming charts based on data from parse.com. I have read some examples and tutorials but still have problem with displaying charts. Below is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LineGraph {

    public ArrayList<Integer> dataArray;

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    public static boolean ClickEnabled = true;

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        ArrayList<Integer> y = this.dataArray;

        XYSeries seriesY = new XYSeries("Y");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
            seriesY.add(i, y.get(i));
        }
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(seriesY);

        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setClickEnabled(ClickEnabled);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setChartTitle("Simple data");
        renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
        return intent;
    }

    public void getData() {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Counters_data");
        query.getInBackground("lxFzCTeOcl", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    String object = parseObject.getString("value");
                    Integer objectValue = Integer.parseInt(object);
                    if (dataArray == null) {
                        dataArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        dataArray.add(objectValue);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And there is how I invoke charts:

```
public void lineGraphHandler(View view) {
        LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
        line.getData();
        Intent lineIntent = line.getIntent(this);
        startActivity(lineIntent);
    }
```

And XML part:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/counters"
        android:onClick="lineGraphHandler"
        android:text="Charts"
        android:id="@+id/charts"/>
```

There is my logcat:

> 03-26 08:42:13.096 1229-1229/com.example.tst D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling
>   CheckJNI 03-26 08:42:13.487 1229-1229/com.example.tst D/libEGL﹕ loaded
>   /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so 03-26 08:42:13.491
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host
>   Connection established 0xb94f4270, tid 1229 03-26 08:42:13.551
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst D/libEGL﹕ loaded
>   /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so 03-26 08:42:13.551
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst D/libEGL﹕ loaded
>   /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so 03-26 08:42:14.035
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not
>   implemented 03-26 08:42:14.039 1229-1229/com.example.tst
>   E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 03-26
>   08:42:14.043 1229-1229/com.example.tst E/OpenGLRenderer﹕
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096 03-26 08:42:14.055 1229-1229/com.example.tst
>   E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from
>   Caches::initConstraints() 03-26 08:42:14.063 1229-1229/com.example.tst
>   E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096 03-26 08:42:14.063
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   03-26 08:42:50.327 1229-1229/com.example.tst D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC
>   freed 200K, 8% free 2975K/3228K, paused 10ms, total 13ms 03-26
>   08:42:51.675 1229-1229/com.example.tst D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
>   431K, 14% free 3056K/3540K, paused 22ms, total 28ms 03-26 08:42:52.043
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not
>   implemented 03-26 08:42:53.543 1229-1229/com.example.tst
>   I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 89 frames! The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 03-26 08:43:01.747
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 03-26
>   08:43:01.747 1229-1229/com.example.tst W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d8fb20) 03-26 08:43:01.767
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.tst, PID: 1229 java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Could not execute method of the activity at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823) at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)             at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)             at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)             at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)             at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)             at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.tst.LineGraph.getIntent(LineGraph.java:36) at
>   com.example.tst.MainActivity.lineGraphHandler(MainActivity.java:44)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)             at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)             at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)             at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)             at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)             at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)             at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-26 08:43:04.507
>   1229-1229/com.example.tst I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1229 SIG: 9

I don't understand where the problem is. My app starts but crashes immediately when I push "chart" button. Is it data type of problem or because I misunderstand something?
Thank you in advance.

I tried like this but still got crash:

```
public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    String object = parseObject.getString("value");
                    Integer objectValue = Integer.parseInt(object);
                    if (dataArray == null) {
                        dataArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        dataArray.add(objectValue);

                        ArrayList<Integer> y = dataArray;
                        XYSeries seriesY = new XYSeries("Y");
                        for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
                            seriesY.add(i, y.get(i));

                            dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                            dataset.addSeries(seriesY);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: can u show ur logcat ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getData()` retrieves the data asynchronously. `dataArray` won't be initialized immediately when you call `getIntent()`.

Wait for the async operation to complete before using the data there. For example, call the code requiring that data from the `done()` callback.